# MPMoviePlayerController Load Video From Camera Roll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a Xamarin.ios app that needs to play a video from the camera roll. The app records a video from the camera and then saves it to the camera roll. I then need to play this recording in the app. I have the OutputFileUrl from the e.g.

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/872214F0-8C50-46ED-854C-D0C51AF11508/tmp/64E56883-701E-451D-8964-D974C17CAE7E-294-0000001438002E09.mov
```

However, if I pass this to the constructor of the MPMoviePlayerController it does not play e.g.

```
moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController(new NSUrl("file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/872214F0-8C50-46ED-854C-D0C51AF11508/tmp/64E56883-701E-451D-8964-D974C17CAE7E-294-0000001438002E09.mov"));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Moving comment to answer in case it is correct. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it looks like that might be a temp directory rather than the url of the video in the Camera Roll. I am not very familiar with this, but it might be that once you save it to the camera roll that the temp file is deleted. But the only way I can see to get the URL for the video in the camera roll is to use the UIImagePickerController which allows the user to select a video to play from their photos library. If you don't want to use a UIImagePickerController, then perhaps you should save the video to the App's documents folder as well as saving it to the camera roll?